# Find a Text Pattern in python Data Frame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame having column with Chat Transcript.

```
ID  Chat
1   P1: Please call me soon P2 - will call you
2   P2: Please call me soon P1 - will call you
```

I want to create a new column with yes/No or 1/0 if chat has pattern "call me soon" only between P1 & P2 But not between P2 & P1.

Out put will be like

```
ID  Chat                                          Call me soon
1   P1: Please call me soon P2 - will call you        Yes
2   P2: Please call me soon P1 - will call you         No
```

I need to do it in python. Please suggest a appropriate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.contains` + `np.where`:

```
df['Call me soon'] = np.where(
    df.Chat.str.contains('(?<=P1).*?call me soon.*?(?=P2)'), 'Yes', 'No'
)

df
   ID                                        Chat Call me soon
0   1  P1: Please call me soon P2 - will call you          Yes
1   2  P2: Please call me soon P1 - will call you           No
```

**Regex Details**

```
(?<=P1)       # lookbehind, match P1
.*?           # any character - non-greedy
call me soon
.*?       
(?=P2)        # lookahead, match P2
```